# How to put display equations (with some space around them) inline?

Tags: math-mode, equations, horizontal-alignment

I want to write an equation that behaves like inline-math w.r.t to horizontal alignment (i.e., the equations’ left edge is where the text before it ends; and the text after it is indented, so it starts behind the equation), but like display-math w.r.t. to vertical alignment (equation sits between two lines of text, math is `\displaystyle`)

Vaguely what I want:

```
... in the middle of some paragraph explaining whatever maths is
happening so we get
                     T = EQUATION
                                   such that this line continues
where we left off...
```

(I don’t really know how to phrase this well, I hope it’s still understandable)

Comment: Are you sure that's a good idea? The resulting page will looked very jagged.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I’m not asking if I should do this, but *how* to do this. It’s how I tend to format my handwritten notes, and I like how it looks there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a surprisingly complex problem, but doable, and the solution will give a nice tour through TeX’s display mechanism.

This is a global overview of the solution:

- First, the equation is pre-composed in a separate box, so that we can determine its dimensions.
- Then, we try and ensure there is enough space for the equation, by manipulating the `\parfillskip`.
- We place the box we pre-composed in an ordinary display, whose dimensions and positioning we impose manually with the `\displayindent` and `\displaywidth` parameters.
- The length of the line before the equation can be found, once we are inside the display, in `\predisplaysize`.
- Finally, we start the next line with the proper indentation.

The interaction between the `\parfillskip` and the `\predisplaysize` is particularly subtle:

- First, we set `\parfillskip` to the width of the equation, plus infinite stretch. This ensures we have enough room, but may result in overfull lines.
- To this, we add a *shrink* equal to the width of the equation. This prevents overfull lines, but throws our ensurance of having enough room overboard again.
- Now the wonderful thing is that TeX sets `\predisplaysize` to `\maxdimen` if and only if no infinite stretch is applied in the `\parfillskip`. So by this value can we now know if enough room has been made.

The complete solution involves a few more edge cases, and careful treatment of the spacing around the equation:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia, unicode-math}

\begin{document}

% extra horizontal and vertical spacing
\newskip \inlineEqHskip
    \inlineEqHskip = 4pt plus 2pt
\newskip \inlineEqVskip
    \inlineEqVskip = 4pt plus 2pt

% registers for storing intermediate results
\newdimen \inlineEqWidth
\newbox \inlineEqBox

\newenvironment{inline equation}
%
% code for the \begin of the environment
%
    {\ifvmode % special case: no paragraph text preceding the equation
        % compensate for the following \strut
        \kern -\ht\strutbox
        \kern -\dp\strutbox
        % start a paragraph
        \noindent
        \kern -\inlineEqHskip
    \fi
    % spacing before the equation
    \unskip \nobreak % prevent line breaks here
    \hskip\inlineEqHskip % horizontal space
    \strut % make previous spaces undiscardable
    % store the equation in a box
    \setbox\inlineEqBox = \hbox\bgroup
        $\displaystyle} % start of box contents
%
% code for the \end of the environment
%
    {$\egroup % close the box we opened above
    \begingroup % assignments will be local by default
    % adjust vertical spacing (note that we are inside a group)
    \abovedisplayskip = \inlineEqVskip
    \belowdisplayskip = \inlineEqVskip
    % ensure there is enough space left for this equation:
    % the ‘minus’ part prevents overfull line messages
    \parfillskip = \wd\inlineEqBox plus 1 fill minus \wd\inlineEqBox
    $$ % open the real equation so we can change the display spacing variables
    \displaywidth = \wd\inlineEqBox % otherwise equal to the line width
    \ifdim \predisplaysize < \maxdimen % true if we have enough room
        \advance \predisplaysize by -2em % tex adds 2em by itself
        \advance \displayindent by \predisplaysize
    \else % edge case: the equation cannot fit on the line
        % this causes the \parfillskip to have no infinite stretch applied,
        % which makes TeX set \predisplaysize to \maxdimen
        \predisplaysize = 0pt
    \fi
    % calculate the offset of the next line
    \global \inlineEqWidth = \dimexpr
        \wd\inlineEqBox + \predisplaysize + \inlineEqHskip \relax
    % add the box we made and close the equation
    \box \inlineEqBox $$
    % start the next line
    \strut \hskip \inlineEqWidth % horizontal space
    \allowbreak % the equation may end a line
    \endgroup \ignorespaces}

% example paragraphs

\hrule

\noindent
An example,
\begin{inline equation}
    1 + 1 + 1 = 3,
\end{inline equation}
of an inline display equation.

\hrule

\noindent
At the end of a line, however, or with a very long equation,
\begin{inline equation}
    1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 5,
\end{inline equation}
you may run into trouble and, though we can detect this situation, it will not 
look very nice.

\hrule

\begin{inline equation}
    1 + 1 = 2
\end{inline equation}
Starting a paragraph with an inline display is also detectable, but hard to 
find an appropriate solution for.

\hrule

\end{document}
```

[image: Three example paragraphs.]

Comment: wow this really is complicated..